# Doc Shell Swapping Example

Tags: firefox-addon

I'm trying to write a simple example to show docshell swapping from one iframe to another.

I wrote this, can run from scratchpad with environment browser:

```
var doc = gBrowser.contentDocument;
var iframeA = doc.createElement('iframe');
iframeA.setAttribute('id', 'a');
iframeA.setAttribute('src', 'http://www.bing.com');
doc.documentElement.appendChild(iframeA);

var iframeB = doc.createElement('iframe');
iframeB.setAttribute('id', 'b');
iframeB.setAttribute('src', 'data:text/html,swap to here');
doc.documentElement.appendChild(iframeB);

doc.defaultView.setTimeout(function() {
  var srcFrame = iframeA;
  var targetFrame = iframeB;
  doc.defaultView.alert('will swap now');
  srcFrame.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIFrameLoaderOwner).swapFrameLoaders(targetFrame)
  doc.defaultView.alert('swap done');
}, 5000)
```

However this throws this error when it tries to swap:

```
/*
TypeError: Argument 1 of HTMLIFrameElement.swapFrameLoaders does not implement interface XULElement. Scratchpad/1:17
*/
```

Any ideas on how to fix?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @mook  and @mossop from irc #extdev for the help.

The reason it didnt work was because:

- pretty sure it needs to be a
- Looks like gBrowser.contentDocument might be a html page? You must be using XUL elements
- No idea if it even works in content either - I think it doesn't
- and the things to be swapped must either both be type=content or neither can be, or something like that (translation: the `type` attribute of both source and target must be the same. so if one is `content-primary` the other must be `content-primary` as well)

This works:

```
var doc = document; //gBrowser.contentDocument;
var iframeA = doc.createElementNS('http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul', 'browser');
iframeA.setAttribute('id', 'a');
iframeA.setAttribute('src', 'http://www.bing.com');
iframeA.setAttribute('style', 'height:100px;');
doc.documentElement.appendChild(iframeA);

var iframeB = doc.createElementNS('http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul', 'browser');
iframeB.setAttribute('id', 'b');
iframeB.setAttribute('src', 'data:text/html,swap to here');
iframeB.setAttribute('style', 'height:100px;');
doc.documentElement.appendChild(iframeB);

doc.defaultView.setTimeout(function() {
  var srcFrame = iframeA;
  var targetFrame = iframeB;
  doc.defaultView.alert('will swap now');
  srcFrame.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIFrameLoaderOwner).swapFrameLoaders(targetFrame)
  doc.defaultView.alert('swap done');
}, 5000)
```

---

so in other words even if you made iframe with xul namespace it would not swap if you put it in an html document. like this example here:

```
var xulDoc = document;
var doc = gBrowser.contentDocument;
var iframeA = xulDoc.createElementNS('http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul', 'iframe');
iframeA.setAttribute('id', 'a');
iframeA.setAttribute('src', 'http://www.bing.com');
iframeA.setAttribute('type', 'content');
iframeA.setAttribute('style', 'height:100px;width:100px;');
doc.documentElement.appendChild(iframeA);

var iframeB = xulDoc.createElementNS('http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul', 'iframe');
iframeB.setAttribute('id', 'b');
iframeB.setAttribute('src', 'data:text/html,swap to here');
iframeB.setAttribute('type', 'content');
iframeB.setAttribute('style', 'height:100px;width:100px;');
doc.documentElement.appendChild(iframeB);

doc.defaultView.setTimeout(function() {
  var srcFrame = iframeA;
  var targetFrame = iframeB;
  doc.defaultView.alert('will swap now');
  srcFrame.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIFrameLoaderOwner).swapFrameLoaders(targetFrame)
  doc.defaultView.alert('swap done');
}, 5000)
```

It throws:

```
NS_ERROR_NOT_IMPLEMENTED:  Scratchpad/2:21
```

this line is the `swapFrameLoaders` line

---

so its recommended to not use iframe with xul namespace as if you do you wont get the DOMContentLoaded and some other events http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=2809781&hilit=iframe+html+namespace

so its recommended to use  element