# Pre-Open Links in a Webpage using Firefox Addon SDK

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I want to pre-open HTTPS connections (using a proxy) to every server that is linked in a Webpage, so that when a User clicks on a link the connection to the server has already been established.

Anybody got a hint how to achieve this with Firefox Addon SDK? I think I have to use a content script first to parse the Webpage for the links and then connect to every server using the '@mozilla.org/network/socket-transport-service' class?

Comment: Fire a xmlhttprequest on all of them. Or this is a crazy idea: load them all into a bunch of iframes and when user clicks that link then docshell swap it for absolute instant page load http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26721744/doc-shell-swapping-example

Answer (score 0):

use HTML5 `rel="prefetch"` or `rel="preconnect"` [attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Link_types) on the link. IDK if this will work because the addon has to fire before the content is parsed as the DOM to take effect